# Restrictive or non-restrictive participle phrase?

Tags: commas

While writing this sentence in fiction, should I put in a comma after "fanned out" or should I withhold it to imply restrictive use?

> They fanned out looking for Justin.

Comment: I don't think "looking for Justin" is a participle phrase. If it was a participle phrase what would it modify?  Not "they" since it describes what they are *doing*, not what they *are*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Should I use a comma in this sentence?

Comment: You can, but that's now how I would write it. To me, "fanned out looking" is a kind of *compound* verb, but I'm sure there's a more linguistic name for it.

Comment: "Looking for Justin" is a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct -- a modifier in clause structure.